# LayoutWeights not properly scaling elements

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I am trying to use `layout_weight` to have a button appear just to the right of a `EditText` field.

However, this is what happens:

[image]

Is there any way to get the compiled version to look like my design view?

Here is my Design View

[image]

And here is my layout code:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
android:padding="10dp"
android:scrollbars="none"
tools:context="com.mycomapany.myapp.Views.MasterDetails.VehicleFragment">


<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/llMainView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">


../// OTHER ELEMENTS

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:hint="VIN">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/editVIN"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:background="@color/COLOR_TXI_GREY"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLength="17"
        android:maxLines="1"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/pbCheckVIN"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnScanVIN"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/COLOR_TXI_BLUE"
    android:text="SCAN"
    android:textColor="@color/COLOR_TXI_WHITE"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
</LinearLayout>


../// OTHER ELEMENTS

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here just a one step answer, just remove the **TextInputEditText** background and mention it is

> Java
>   android:background="@android:color/transparent"

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"` attribute from `TextInputEditText`

Comment: Please try to provide context with your answer.  An answer may solve a problem, but an explanation may solve many future problems.  Try to include what you think is causing the issue and why your answer will solve it.

Comment: @Newd android:layout_marginEnd specifies extra space on the end of the view outside the view's bounds. This, I believe, is causing the space between EditText and Button.